# Preventing the Lost Update Problem without inconveniencing my consumers

Tags: rest, architecture, software-design, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

I have a fairly simple set of API's

```
GET /documents
GET /documents/:id
PATCH /documents/:id
```

To prevent the "lost update" problem, I want to send an `Etag` back on `GET /documents/:id` and then require that value is sent in a `If-Match` header on the `PATCH` request. I will then query my db, generate an `Etag` based on the result, and check if the `Etag` matches what the user passed in to determine if the record has not been updated underneath them. Pretty common stuff here.

My question relates to the `GET /documents` call. If a consumer calls `GET /documents` to get all their documents, finds the one they want to update, they will then have to issue a call to `GET /documents/:id` to get the `Etag` of that record, then they can finally issue the `PATCH /documents/:id` call.

I'm curious what others have done to circumvent this extra call to `GET /documents/:id` just to get the `Etag`, yet still prevent the "lost update" problem?

Comment: Don't think you can (or should) try to circumvent it. Optimizations can be to expose a HEAD method on the get-ID resource for getting the etag. Or in-line the etag header in the body of the get-list api. If the clients are allowed to cache, you can add a If-none-match header on the get-ID api to help the client along.

Comment: I thought about etag in the body and am still thinking about doing that possibly. No caching at this point in time. Never thought about HEAD although it's not much more lightweight than the actual GET request since both have to query the db and generate an Etag

Answer (score 0):

Include the `Etag` as a property of a document in addition to including it in the header when appropriate. This will both save roundtrips and make it easier for clients to access the `Etag` when persisting a document locally beyond the scope of the initial call.

Comment: One caveat to keep in mind, if your etag computation is expensive,then you're basically computing the etag for all the resources in the response while the client will probably use only one. It will increase the load on your server. This can be alleviated somewhat with aggressive client side caching & an if-none-match header for the get-api